# How to get data from server's database in HTML 5, using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have HTML files.
They are just local files, so it is not connected to a certain server.
I want to connect this to a server I made and make it alive.

I don't want any code that works for real. That's cheating, I know.
I am just starting making a website from nothing so all I want is just keywords and pseudo code.
Keywords for what I should google, and pseudo-code for how things are going to look like.

I have a database and a back-end server that can get and return any queries,
or preprocess before sending them.

Meanwhile in HTML,

```html
...
<div class="article-body">
    <div id='words'><h3>Apple</h3><br>the round fruit of a tree of the rose family.</div>
    ...
    <div id='words'><h3>Banana</h3><br>a long curved fruit which grows in clusters.</div>
</div>
...
```

I have this kind of codes. It is hard coded.

And I want to connect this to React or something and make this look like

```html
...
<script src="dictionary.js"></script>
<div class="article-body">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3>{word}</h3><br>{explanation}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

So it gets data from server db.

What are the keywords that I can search for, or some examples of cases like this?

I know it is a very silly question.
I am really sorry to ask this but I don't have any developers around me
that I can ask this kind of thing.
Thank you for reading this.
May the force be with you.

Comment: I suggest you start at the React.js Getting Started guide - https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html, or try the React.js course at https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/react/

Comment: Thank you `@Ozzy`. I really appreciate that.